# LINQ query to entity framework isn't doing the Include() correctly

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'm doing this query in an entity model that contains the .net membership tables

```
var q = from u in context.aspnet_Users.Include("aspnet_Membership")
                from ud in context.UserDetails
                where u.UserId == ud.UserId
                && ud.CompanyID == CompanyID
                select u;
```

Variable `CompanyID` contains the `id` of the `company` I want to get the `users` out of. Table `UserDetails` is a custom table to relate `user` to `company` and other stuff.

My problem is that property `aspnet_Membership` in the final object is null even though the user exists. Any ideas to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include doesn't work with Joins (stupid, I know):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/3f39e481-3c72-4abe-80b7-c92427747011/

Use a projection as suggested above OR cast your results IQueryable back to an ObjectQuery and include on that:

```
q = ((ObjectQuery<aspnet_User>)q).Include("aspnet_Membership");
```

Comment: Very strange indeed... Well, your cast solution worked out great! Thank you very much =]